# Error with pop() methods on my project

Tags: java, stack, queue

Im creating a project for one of my classes and the objective is to create a queue using a stack. I think I have the general framework for the class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class SQueue {
private Stack<Integer> queue;

public SQueue(Stack<Integer> inputQueue) {
    queue = inputQueue;
}
public void push(int x) {
    Stack<Integer> tempStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> backwardsStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    tempStack.push(x);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    backwardsStack.push(queue.pop());
    }
    while(!backwardsStack.isEmpty()) {
        tempStack.push(backwardsStack.pop());
    }
    queue = tempStack;
}
public int pop() {
    Stack<Integer> tempStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    tempStack.push(queue.pop());
    }
    int temp = tempStack.peek();
    tempStack.pop();
    return temp;
}
public int peek() {
    Stack<Integer> tempStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    tempStack.push(queue.pop());
    }
    int temp = tempStack.peek();
    return temp;        
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return queue.isEmpty();
}
}
```

Im also using the following class for testing:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SQueueTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    SQueue test1 = new SQueue(s);
    SQueue test2 = new SQueue(s);
    SQueue test3 = new SQueue(s);
    case1(test1);
    case2(test2);
    case3(test3);
}
public static void case1(SQueue test) {
    for(int i =1; i <6; i++) {
        test.push(i);
    }
    for(int i =0; i <3; i++) {
        test.pop();
    }
    System.out.println(test.peek());
}
public static void case2(SQueue test) {
    test.push(2);
    test.push(4);
    test.push(8);
    for(int i =0; i <2; i++) {
        test.pop();
    }
    System.out.println(test.isEmpty());
}
public static void case3(SQueue test) {
    for(int i = 1; i<4; i++) {
        test.push(i*3);
    }
    test.pop();
    System.out.println(test.peek());
    System.out.println(test.isEmpty());
}
}
```

After running the program I received this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at SQueue.pop(SQueue.java:27)
at SQueueTest.case1(SQueueTest.java:19)
at SQueueTest.main(SQueueTest.java:10)
```

Im not sure how to proceed with solving this error because while I was bug testing the temp variable in the pop() method stored the right int, 5, but then removed that digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your `pop()` method (also in `peek()`), you are successfully removing the first element from your sQueue, but you never push back all of the elements from your tempStack into your `queue` stack. So you are dealing with an empty `queue` when you try to pop off the next element.